# Extension of Cesaro means

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to extend the Cesaro Means result here:
http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~vittorio/CesaroMeans.pdf

The author there proved: $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = a$.

I want to extend this to: $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{(n)}_n = a \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n a^{(n)}_i = a$.

**My attempt so far**:

WLOG assume $a=0$. 
$$
|1/n \sum_{i=1}^n a^{(n)}_i| \leq 1/n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |a^{(n)}_i| + a^{(n)}_n/n 
$$ 
$$
\implies |1/n \sum_{i=1}^n a^{(n)}_i| \leq \frac{(n-1) \max_{i=1,\dots,n-1}|a^{(n)}_i| + a^{(n)}_n}{n} 
$$
So I'm stuck here. This is not an exercise in a book so I'm not sure if my claim is even correct. If it is not true, what are the minimal assumptions I need to place on $a^n_n$ for this to be true.

Comment: Is this not clear because you can just apply the author's result to $a_n^n$ instead of $a_n$?

Comment: @max_zorn: I'm not sure. In his proof, the summands are independent of $n$. Here, it is not the case.

Comment: You are right, it is more complicated. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be generally true. Try a simple example like $a_n = 2^{1/n}$ where $a_n^n \to 2$.

Do you think $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{n/k} \to 2$?

At least $n/4$ terms are bigger than $2^4/n$, $n/8$ terms are bigger than $2^8/n$, etc.

Comment: Do you know what type of conditions I need to place on $a^{(n)}_n$ to make this work?

Comment: It's not too difficult to construct ad hoc examples where it does and does not work. I'll give some thought on how to generalize.  Is there some motivation for this?

Comment: Thanks. The motivation is this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656614/strong-law-of-large-numbers-and-uniform-convergence-on-compact-sets